# provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable - Azure SQL database

Tags: sql-server, azure, connectivity

I get the error `provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable` intermittently when making Entity Framework requests to a database in Azure.

When the problem occurs it affects a little under 1% of requests. But it doesn't occur often or predictably. It happened for a few hours last week and this week, but now everything is fine.

I've checked my connection string db pool size, it is using the default. I tried reducing the pool to 2 connections and this causes a different error.

What else could it be?

Comment: I get the same error. Could not find any solution so far. I tweaked the IIS settings to make the pool more responsive and replaced the domain names with the IP add. in the web.config. My applications runs better but I still receive this error occasionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been a transient issue. Has not happened in a few months.

Comment: thats why you need "defensive" programming. ;-)

Comment: You should check out the Polly Project, it is great for retrying in situations like this. I have a few blog posts on the topic. This one is a good start -
 http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2017/03/a-simple-polly-example-with-webapi-2/

Answer (score 0):

I tried "Recycle" option in IIS in application pool and got rid of this error.